# Breaking down sentence with phrases

Tags: phrases

> **Schools** use the feedback from Cambridge Lower Secondary Checkpoint to make strategic decisions, **drawing upon** a pool of information
>   and specialist reporting tools that are built into the tests.

Source: [Cambridge Lower Secondary Checkpoint](http://www.cambridgeinternational.org/programmes-and-qualifications/cambridge-secondary-1/cambridge-checkpoint/)

The sentence above can be broken down into:

1- Schools use the feedback from Cambridge Lower Secondary Checkpoint to make strategic decisions.

2- Schools draw upon a pool of information and specialist reporting tools that are built into the tests.

Is the analysis correct?

Comment: That is an accurate breakdown.  You could probably break it down into four or five sentences if you wanted to simplify it further.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. The part after the comma is a [participle phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm). This construction is used to avoid repetition of **schools** and to introduce a bit of variety into the text. Here is another example:

> **Cooper** enjoyed dinner at Audrey's house, **agreeing** to a large slice of cherry pie even though he was full to the point of bursting

This is a lot more interesting to read than

> Cooper enjoyed dinner at Audrey's house. Cooper agreed to a large slice of cherry pie even though he was full to the point of bursting

or even

> Cooper enjoyed dinner at Audrey's house. He agreed to a large slice of cherry pie even though he was full to the point of bursting